# Encode video with H.264 using FFmpeg in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I'm trying to encode a video with H.264 using FFmpeg (`AV_CODEC_ID_H264`), but I'm unable to init the codec correctly. No issues at all when using other codec like `AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO`.

```
avcodec_register_all();

auto codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (!codec) { return false; }

auto codec_context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if (!codec_context) { return false; }

codec_context->codec_id = codec->id;
codec_context->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

codec_context->width = w; // w = 1280 on tests
codec_context->height = h; // h = 1024 on tests
codec_context->bit_rate = w * h * 4;

codec_context->time_base = { 1, fps }; // fps = 50 on tests
codec_context->framerate = { fps, 1 };

codec_context->gop_size = 10;

codec_context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
    av_opt_set(codec_context->priv_data, "preset", "veryfast", 0);
}

if (avcodec_open2(codec_context, codec, nullptr) < 0) { return false; } // < Fails here
```

The first error message I received is:

> [h264_amf @ 08e75900] DLL amfrt32.dll failed to open

As far as I was able to find, that DLL belongs to the Advanced Media Framework, a SDK to access HW acceleration from AMD hardware. I don't own an AMD card, so I don't have such drivers nor SDK installed in my computer. Anyway, I downloaded the SDK and copied driver's DLLs to my binaries directory. The missing DLL error was removed, but, as expected, the module was not correctly initialized:

> [h264_amf @ 0375b600] CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderVCE_AVC) failed with error 13

**Question: Am I missing anything (parameters, dependencies)? Is there any way to disable the AMF acceleration or to mark it as optional / auto-detect / whatever?**

PS: I'm expecting to run the encoding executable in a very heterogeneous client-base, assuming Windows 10 and barely anything else, so I can't mark as mandatory vendor-specific accelerations.

PS: I'm using the pre-compiled LGPL build of FFmpeg 4.2.1 from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ for Windows 32 bits. My code is being compiled using Visual Studio 2017.

If the problem is in the pre-compiled version, I'm happy with re-building it. If so, which configuration parameters should I use when building x264 or ffmpeg then?

Comment: The software x264 encoder uses libx264 which is GPL and not therefore included in the LGPL ffmpeg build

Comment: @AlanBirtles oh! thanks, yes, I've tested with the GPL build and it loads correctly. Thanks for the information. Please feel free to add it as an answer to accept it. If you have information about commercial options (including licensing fr H.264), I'd appreciate it too. Thanks again.

Comment: `libopenh264` offers a LGPL-based encoder. If you distribute a GPLed ffmpeg build/lib, allow for requests of the source code of the app you're linking with.